# Lookup based on two criteria, one a number and one a range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two lists, one with ID's and percentages based on various ranges, and the other with ID's and totals. I need to look up the percentage in the first spreadsheet based on the ID and total in the second spreadsheet.

```
ID  Bottom Top  Percentage
1   1      50       0.3
1   51     75       0.4
1   76              0.5
2   1               0.75
3   1      25       1
3   26     100      2
3   101    1000     3
3   1001   2000     4
3   2001            5

Second List
ID  Total Amount
1   100
2   146
3   1256
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. To improve your chances of receiving a useful and accurate answer, you should make sure your question has the following: a clear title; a reasonable explanation of what your **question** is with as much detail as you can; and any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem. You can find further information on [ask] in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your first table is on Sheet1 and your second table is on Sheet2 and that you want to populate the Amount column of your second table, the following formula will accomplish this for the first Amount cell (cell C2) of Sheet2.  This requires the first table to be sorted by the ID column and then by the Bottom column.  This formula can be copy-pasted down to the end of table 2 after it has been entered.

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, OFFSET(Sheet1!B:D, MATCH(A2, Sheet1!A:A, 0) - 1, 0, COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A, A2)), 3)
```

Note that the Top column is not actually necessary for this to work.

Breaking this formula down, it uses the [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-IN/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) function to search the Bottom column for the closest value lower than or equal to the Total value, and then returns the value in the Percentage column for the same row.  It also has to limit the search to rows matching the correct ID, and it does this with the [`OFFSET`](https://support.office.com/en-IN/article/offset-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) function.  The [`OFFSET`](https://support.office.com/en-IN/article/offset-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) function uses the row of the first matching ID found with the [`MATCH`](https://support.office.com/en-IN/article/MATCH-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function and the total count of matching IDS found with the [`COUNTIF`](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/COUNTIF-function-4764f197-0127-49fa-9f5a-b188177b6db4) function.

Comment: Thank you, this is very enlightening. I guess I should've been more clear in what value I wanted to have returned. I'm looking to populate the percentage column in table 2 based on the ID and amount in table 2 by referencing the data in table 1.

ID  Bottom Top  Percentage
1   1      50       0.3
1   51     75       0.4
1   76              0.5
2   1               0.75
3   1      25       1
3   26     100      2
3   101    1000     3
3   1001   2000     4
3   2001            5

Second List
ID  Total     Percentage
1   100
2   146
3   1256

Comment: Actually, this formula works perfectly. Thank you!